# How to display random data from ArrayList in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist

I have a list of apps installed on the device. Now I want to show a list of 10-20 (the number of applications should always be different) random applications, how can I do this in Kotlin?

My code:

```
private fun onGetApps() {
        val pm: PackageManager = requireContext().packageManager
        val apps: List<PackageInfo> = requireContext().packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
        val res: ArrayList<Apps> = ArrayList<Apps>()

        for (i in apps.indices) {

            if (pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage (apps[i].packageName) != null)
            {
                val p = apps[i]

                val appInfo = Apps()

                appInfo.appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(requireContext().packageManager).toString()
                appInfo.appImage = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(requireContext().packageManager)
                res.add(appInfo)
            }

            mAdapter.setupApps(res)
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to shuffle elements randomly and take first `n` of them:

```kotlin
println((0..10).shuffled().take(3))
```

If the number of all items is much bigger than the number of items to take then it probably makes sense to use a sequence:

```kotlin
println((0..10).asSequence().shuffled().take(3).toList())
```

Note that in the case the number of items to get is bigger than the number of all items, it will return all items in the source collection.

In your case it will be something like:

```kotlin
val res = apps.asSequence()
    .filter { pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(it.packageName) != null }
    .shuffled()
    .take((10..20).random())
    .map { p ->
        val appInfo = Apps()

        appInfo.appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(requireContext().packageManager).toString()
        appInfo.appImage = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(requireContext().packageManager)
        
        appInfo
    }.toList()
```

Comment: Code inside `map()` can be further improved with `also()`/`apply()`, but I didn't want to add too much confusion.

Comment: The fact is that I have to select a random number of applications in Recнcler View, the number of these applications should always be different but in the range from 10 to 20. I also need to always show a different list of applications.

Comment: Yes, you said this already in the question description. What do you mean exactly with your comment? I guess one thing that is missing in my solution is that the `10` should not be fixed, but should be a random number between 10 and 20, correct? Is there anything else that is missing here?

Comment: val res = apps.asSequence() there must be an ArrayList so I can add to the adapter

Comment: What is this adapter that requires `ArrayList` specifically? It really doesn't make too much sense. `ArrayAdapter` requires array or `List`. `ListAdapter` requires `List`. If you created the `setupApps()` function and it requires `ArrayList` then I suggest changing it to `List` or `MutableList`. As you can see, requiring `ArrayList` results with compatibility problems with other code. Anyway, you can get `ArrayList` from my solution by changing `map { ... }` to: `mapTo(ArrayList()) { ... }` and removing `toList()` at the end.

Comment: I've already figured it out. Your answer helped me a lot. I'll mark it as accepted